# Bind an IEnumerable column inside a gridview templatefield

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have the following setup

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridRepresentatives" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCommand="BtnSubmitCommand" OnRowCreated="GridRepresentativesCreated" CssClass="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="You don't have rights to manage any organisations.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roles">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownRoles" DataMember="Roles" Width="205px">    
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownActions" Width="100px">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Edit" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Remove" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Go"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="grid-actions"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternate"></AlternatingRowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
 var client = new RepresentativeManagementServiceClient();
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Representative> representatives =     client.ListRepresentatives("01", _organisationId, role);
                gridRepresentatives.DataSource = representatives;
                gridRepresentatives.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = ex.Message;
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            }
```

The gridview binds to IEnumerable of Type Represenative which has as set of public propreties. I want to bind the IEnumerable Roles property inside to a dropdownlist inside the gridview templatefield. I've tried to set the Datamember to the name of the property(Roles), but it just does not bind and does not throw any errors. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you lost your `Representative` class? I'm not sure but I think if you set `Roles` to `DataSource` or `DropDown` instead of `DataMember` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to bind the data source for that drop down:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roles">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownRoles" DataSource='<%# Eval("Roles") %>' Width="205px">    
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this is it. I don't know why the DataSource property does not show up in the intellisense, it could save alot of trouble for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up  `SelectedValue` property of DropDownList. Intellisence does not show it up for some reason, but you can use it like this

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roles">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Roles") %>'>    
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

But before binding it, you should full up DropDown with possible values. Manualy or using some
datasource(I think `ObjectDataSource` will be good in your case)

Comment: There's no "SelectedValue", a representative can have one or more roles. I just want to show all the roles the representative has inside the dropdown.